# DHCP error while WinPhone8 emulator is starting

Tags: windows-8, dhcp, windows-phone-8

I had a Windows 8 PC with a perfectly working WinPhone8 emulator.

A few days ago my OS broke and our IT guys reinstalled Windows 8 in identical configuration. I installed the WinPhone SDK and tried to run the emulator without success (with message similar to `your Hyper-V isn't enabled` although it was enabled).

After fully patching (I installed SDK before that), the emulator started but I got
the error `You don't have permission to modify internal hyper-v network adapter settings`.

[image]

When I clicked `Retry` I got a message about a possible issue with the network, so I pressed OK and my PC crashed within a short time after the emulator initialized.

I added my user to `Hyper-V Administrators` but this also changed nothing (PC still crashing). I checked `Event Viewer` and found there next message.

> Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the
>   DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0xE02A82E2702D.
>   The following error occurred: 0x79. Your computer will continue to try
>   and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP)
>   server.

I googled about this issue and found the suggestion to turn off the `Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)`, but this didn't help.

Does anybody have any idea about how to fix it?

Comment: Information about the crash is required to help you.

Comment: @Ramhound OS freezes and no way to do something instead of reboot pc. I had checked Event Log after reboot and found message about DHCP. It is all that I have. Do you need any specific details?

Comment: Without information on the crash, generated by Windows, a resolution to your problem is unlikely. Have you tried to uninstall recently installed software?  I suggest you report your problems to your IT staff they are in the best position to help you.

Comment: @Ramhound Frankly, you confuse me. When I start emulator - OS freezes and everything that I can do - reboot it. I had checked Event Log after reboot and sow message that I mentioned in question. What kind of details do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be caused by the newer SDK that you are now using.

One possibility would be to go back to the older version that worked, but there is
another solution described in the article :
[Troubleshooting Windows Phone 8 Emulator problems](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/petevickers/archive/2012/11/01/troubleshooting-windows-phone-8-emulator-problems.aspx) :

- Run the `Hyper-V Manager`, and click on the `Virtual Switch Manager`.
- If there is no entry resembling `Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch`, click on `New Virtual Switch`, choose `Internal` and then `Create Virtual Switch`.
  Create a new entry called `Windows Phone Emulator Internal Switch` and then click on OK - this will create the emulator switch.
- Open the `Network and Sharing Center` by right clicking on your Network icon in the system tray or accessing it via the Control Panel. Then click on `Change adapter settings`. You will see a list of your network adapters, including the one we have just created.
- Right-click on the adapter, and select Properties.
- Untick all the items except for:

  - Client for Microsoft Networks
  - QoS Packet Scheduler
  - File and Printer Sharing for Microsoft Networks
  - Microsoft LLDP Protocol Driver
  - Link-Layer Topology Discovery Mapper I/O Driver
  - Link-Layer Topology Discovery Responder
  - Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
  - Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4)
- Click on OK.
- Reboot

You may need to disable your VMware adapters or you may not. If you still have problems, you can check what network adapter your emulator is using by running Hyper-V Manager. You can see the list of virtual machines running. Click on one of the emulators, and then at the bottom, click on the `Networking` tab, and you can see which network adapter your emulator is using.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't help completely. Emulator was started without any window. But it is still crashed. In event log I see next: "The driver \Driver\WudfRd failed to load for the device ROOT\WPD\0000.", "Your computer was not assigned an address from the network (by the DHCP Server) for the Network Card with network address 0xE02A82E2702F.  The following error occurred: 0x79. Your computer will continue to try and obtain an address on its own from the network address (DHCP) server.",

Comment: Could you add to your post what happens when you try following the above procedure? Also, are you using the same SDK version as before or is it a newer version ?

Comment: I am using same SDK version. I run app, emulator was started after this Operation System (Windows 8) was freezed (stopped to work). And no way to do anything except hardware reboot. After reboot I checked event log and sow errors with DHCP. I don't have any other errors.

Comment: You would need to find what is different in your current setup from before.

Comment: Looks like my question is related to hardware issue (I got some other issues with my PC). But your answer helps me with issue related to permissions, so I awarded this.